# Proxy pass after condition Apache

Tags: apache, proxy, configuration, conditional-statements, proxypass

I am trying to configure apache httpd.conf file `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` using rewrite rule after services location depending on condition as below.  But I logically cannot apply it on redirection rule as Apache does not start giving error "Delimiters flags syntax" on the rewrite rule lines.

```
<Location /services/>
    Allow from all

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>    
        <If "%{HTTP:api-version} =~ m#^$#">
            ## y 12 FEB 2021 y
            RequestHeader set Host "y.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com"
        </If>
        <Else>
            ## x 8 FEB 2021 x
            RequestHeader set Host "x.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com"
        </Else>
    </IfModule>

    ### MY Cluster 
    #ProxyPass  https://10.230.75.32/
    #ProxyPassReverse https://10.230.75.32/

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:api-version} =~ m#^$# 
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://y.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/$1  ##if condition accepted 
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://x.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/$2  ## else condition 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://y.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://x.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/ 

    ErrorPage https://mobile.pvd.com/HTML/genericError_en.htm
```

Comment: Show the exact error log entry.  Run `apache -t` and show the output if there is any error.  Have you tried moving the `RewriteRule` - `ProxyPassReverse` within the `<If> <else>` sections?

Comment: Hello Nick this is last log.

And Yes I tried moving the Proxy pass part in the if and else section it gave syntax error on the beginning and as per apache documentation its not possible to do so . 

[Fri Feb 12 04:23:58.526058 2021] [so:warn] [pid 87060:tid 139860289816832] AH01574: module unique_id_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00526: Syntax error on line 343 of /apache/jbcs-httpd24-2.4/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters.

it is showing the error in the first line of the Rewrite rule but i think this block its not Written logically correct .

Comment: A RewriteRule that you want act as a proxy requires the [P] flag at the end.  And you have 2 rules with the same regex, `^/(.*)`.  Apache will only use the first one it finds.  And that matches everything!

Comment: so it should go like this i guess 

 RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:api-version} =~ m#^$# 
    RewriteRule ^/(y.*) http://y.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/  ##if condition accepted 
    RewriteRule ^/(x.*) http://x.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/  ## else condition 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://y.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://x.mobileapp-app.ocp-prod.dceg.pvd.com/

Comment: ah yes, much better.  Apache needs something to differentiate both rules, and your addition of `x` and `y` will help for sure.